# how to access behave.ini and run multiple features in behave 1.2.6

Tags: python, python-behave

I want to define the order in which to run selected feature files. I defined following in behave.ini

```
[behave]
name=feature2.feature
     feature1.feature
```

and then run behave, but it doesn't pick up the feature list as defined in behave.ini, rather runs all feature files alphabetically. I tried putting behave.ini at project level and under features directory and running behave command from project level as well as features folder level, respectively. I read somewhere we can define a feature_list.txt with the order of features file - am not able to get that reference.Client wants to see a config file.

I also tried -n on command line, that also did not work.

Comment: `name` only specifies which tests to run, not the order of them.  Have you read the documentation?  https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gherkin.html

Comment: I have gone through documentation several times. But what is documented is not happening. It does not even decide which features to run, it runs all the features. Is there a way by which I could decide the order in which features must run?

Comment: I ran behave -v and saw that the configuration defined in behave.ini is picked up but all the feature files are run, not only the ones listed in name list.

Comment: `name` is used to specify a pattern for specific features.  You can use `include` to specify a list of feature files.